# Desktop App Crash When Crawling Data?

Tags: dll, module, import.io, crash

I'm trying to crawl a website's data using Import.io desktop app, I'm running this software on a windows server 2008 r2 64bit,32 GB Ram & intel 4770 i7 CPU, But when it's crawling , Suddenly an error appears which asks me to restart the program, The error description contains :

```
    Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: import.io.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    553e7d2c
  Fault Module Name:    mozalloc.dll
  Fault Module Version: 24.0.0.5001
  Fault Module Timestamp:   522fa8df
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 0000119c
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I've tried to download a new mozalloc.dll and replace the old one with the newer version. Which in this case , Import.io app uses xulrunner version 24, First I've replaced mozalloc.dll version 42 (newest version) with the default import.io's mozalloc.dll file at :

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\import.io\xulrunner-versions\24
```

But after that , the program interface wasn't showing up. When I opened import.io , it does open in the task manager but windows didn't show up the program's interface.
I've also downloaded the newest xulrunner version and replaced all the files in that folder , Same thing happened again.

Comment: Hi there.

I'm afraid I can't answer your problem from the information provided. 

Could you help us identify the issue by providing the GUID of your Crawler? 

Here's how to locate the GUID: 

http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/468761-what-is-a-guid